# ccTLD for international website

Tags: seo, top-level-domains, cctld

How much does it hurt to have a ccTLD (for example candi.es) for an internal website? I read everywhere that a gTLD is recommended but if my website has global links, a US postal address written, etc. would Google be smart enough to understand that the site is not related to Spain at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.es suggests that the domain will be a Spanish language site targeting Spain.

This isn't to say it won't appear in Google searches from other regions - but it's going to appear less relevant than other searches because you've chosen a fixed ccTLD.

Based on that, I would not recommend this. Instead pick a global domain or one that targets your locale/language.